# OpenGL, drawing some Rects (TriangleFan and LineLoop) takes up to 10ms

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertex

Currently I'm wondering why OpenGl needs so much time on drawing some simple TriangleFans with LineLoops around (for smooth edges).

This loop is executed on each onDrawFrame() call.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
        float rotationAngle= (float) ((j * angle) + angleBegin
                - plusAngle+ (angle/ 2f));
        GLES10.glPushMatrix();
        GLES10.glTranslatef(plusX, 0, 1f);

        GLES10.glTranslatef(0.5f * height, 0.5f * height, 0.001f);
        GLES10.glRotatef(rotationAngle, 0, 0, 0.9f);

        rectObject.render(GL_Meshobject.PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
        rectObject.render(GL_Meshobject.PrimitiveType.LineLoop);
        GLES10.glPopMatrix();
    }
```

The object which is rendered 40 x 2 (loop) times was created this way:

```
        rectObject.addColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    rectObject.addVertex(wert1[KOORDS_X], wert1[KOORDS_Y], 0);
    rectObject.addColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    rectObject.addVertex(wert2[KOORDS_X], wert2[KOORDS_Y], 0);
    rectObject.addColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    rectObject.addVertex(wert4[KOORDS_X], wert4[KOORDS_Y], 0);
    rectObject.addColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    rectObject.addVertex(wert3[KOORDS_X], wert3[KOORDS_Y], 0);
```

What's the reason for durations between 2-10ms executing this loop? How can i fix it?

The results of this loop are some rects which are not connected to each other, but is there a a possibility to put this 40 rectangles into one object?

This method draws an part of my background, is it possible to define objects to be rendered only once on the screen like "Rendermode Dirty" but not for the whole Renderer, I would like to avoid creating overlaying SurfaceViews, but there are dynamic and static objects in my onDrawFrame. I would like to render only the dynamic objects and keep the static things on the screen by rendering them only once (at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you loop in the onDraw method? You rotate the mesh 40 times each call. Just increase the angle after or before each onDraw call.

Comment: Hi, I will try this in a moment :) But all rectangles should be seen at the same time, all of them. If I only draw one Rectangle in one onDraw call, I don't think it seems to be a background than.